# как установить apt-get на centOS 7

Tags: centos

Я пытаюсь установить apt-get пакет, но получаю ошибку

```
[root@server ~]# sudo yum install apt-get
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * epel: mirror.umd.edu
 * extras: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * updates: mirror.rackspace.com
No package apt-get available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Как правильно его установить?

Answer (score 4):

APT - менеджер пакетов для **DEB**(ian)-подобных дистрибутивов.
Вы используете **CentOS**, дистрибутив, где **RPM** основной способ установки пакетов.
Пакетами и их зависимостями управляет yum - apt там не может существовать.
Если вам необходимо повторить инструкции с установкой пакетов через apt просто ищите их через yum search [имя пакета без версии] и ставьте через yum install.
Но! В виду того, что обычно инструкции включают в себя еще и правку конфигов и просмотр логов, в RedHat эти пути и названия немного различаются, и если вы совсем новичок в этом вопросе, то либо ищите инструкцию под редхат с рпм, либо поставьте себе Debian-подобный дистрибутив.